# Get Facebook Like list with javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, list, sdk, facebook-like

Is there a way to get all the "likes" that a logged user did with the Facebook javascript SDK ?

OR

Is there a way to display a like button if it has never been liked before ? (to make it impossible to unlike anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is in hear GraphAPI:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

you also can read there:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: it's not possible to block the unlike button, at least with facebook api!